# How to list all files in folder by start name in vb.net without loop

Tags: file, directory

How to list all files in folder by start name but without loop?

Example: in my folder there are files:

```html
filename1.jpg<br/>
filename2.jpg<br/>
filename3.jpg<br/>
kienvt01.jpg<br/>
kienvt02.jpg<br/>
kienvt03.jpg<br/>
....<br/>
...<br/>
```

i want to list all file with file name start with "kienvt", but not using loop.
i'd try with `Directory.GetFiles` but not ok.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim output As String

output = String.Join("<br />", System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "kienvt*"))
```

The value of `output` should be:

```
"kienvt01.jpg<br />kienvt02.jpg<br />kienvt03.jpg<br />"
```